# Graphic cards issue

Tags: upgrade, logs, gpu

I am running a Mac Pro as a kind of server for an application, everything is automated and I am usually using Remote desktop.
Now I have the need to update the Mac version and just realized that the graphics card might be broken as I have tried two different screens without success and in the system profiler the graphics card information is just blank.
In which log files can I check that the graphic card is not found during startup. What would be the procedure to replace the graphic card as I could imagine version problems...

Answer (score 1):

I can't say where the log files are located, though you can be fairly confident that if nothing shows up in the Graphics/Displays then the graphics card will need to be replaced. You can check the display and graphics info from the Terminal as well with `system_profiler SPDisplaysDataType`

I've replaced a few Mac Pro graphics card and the procedure is straightforward. As long as the card is Mac-compatible it's been plug n' play. There are [detailed instructions from Apple](http://manuals.info.apple.com/en/macpro_pciecard_diy.pdf). And plenty of videos on [Youtube](http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=mac+pro+graphics+card+installation&aq=f).

Comment: I have used the profilinf command and it did not show any info as well. I also saw that Apple increased the warranty on the graphics card because of a too high number of failures on the specific card.